# How do I remove the remnants of data from my C: drive?

Tags: cygwin, disk-space

I have installed Cygwin software which contains C++ and c compiler, debugger and some more things. Later on I decided to install all what Cygwin contains in itself. But I run out of memory on `C:` disk. So I stopped installation or extraction. Anyway, Whatever was left on my `C:` disk it takes its space. I want to remove it.

How can I delete those data remnants from HDD?

I tried CCleaner and `C:` disk cleaner, but it did not help.

Comment: Have you checked the recycle bin?

Comment: No, they are not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you installed `cygwin` into `c:\cygwin` simply delete this folder with all it's content.

**But please be aware you also delete you cygwin-users' home directories then. So if you created something under c:\cygwin\home\ you might backup this data prior to deleting.**